# Laravel undefined variable but variable is defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Using laravel I am setting a variable for the layout in the controller:

```
$this->layout->title = 'Foo';
$this->layout->content = View::make('foo.bar');
```

But when I use `$title` in the template I get an `undefined` error:

`<title>{{{ $title }}}</title>`

But if I use a conditional

`<title>{{{ $title or 'Default' }}}</title>`

I get no error and it uses the `$title` variable.

Answer (score -1):

According to Laravel API for [Illuminate\View\View](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.View.View.html#%24data):

```
protected string     $view    The name of the view.
protected array      $data    The array of view data.
```

So to pass data into the view via your controller's property, you need to do:

```
$this->layout->data = array('title' => 'Foo');
```